# Can't merge existing repo when migrating two SVN repos to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-merge, git-svn

I originally had a repo on SVN called repo A. Let's call it's initial commit "commit #1". I made multiple commits to this repo to bring me to commit #3. At this point, I copied the SVN repo to a new location on SVN and continued developing in my copied repo, repo B. Meanwhile, I also continued committing to repo A.

The below describes what the SVN repos looked like:

```
Repo A: 1-2-3-4a-5a-6a
             \
Repo B:       4b-5b-6b
```

Now, at this point, I decided to move both repos to Git. My intention was to clone the two repos and then re-join them in to a single repo, maintaining the separate commits as separate branches sprouting from commit #3 above.

So, I performed the following steps:

```
git svn clone -s -A svn.authors --no-metadata http://subversion.foo.local/repoA_svn/path repoA
git svn clone -s -A svn.authors --no-metadata http://subversion.foo.local/repoB_svn/path repoB
cd repoA
git branch repoA-branch # Branch for first repo
git reset --hard <highest_common_hash> # To have only common history on master
git checkout -b repoB-branch # Branch for second repo
git pull ../repoB master
```

However, once I try to perform the pull operation, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Whilst migrating from SVN, because I had moved repoB's location on SVN previously to separate it from repoA, the link to repoA is lost.

So I have the two Git repos migrated from SVN looking like the below:

```
Repo A: 1-2-3-4a-5a-6a
.
Repo B:       4b-5b-6b
```

As you can see, the link has been broken, thus the unrelated histories error.

**Does anyone know how to add the commits of repoB to repoA, given we are missing the historical link?**

I have tried the --allow-unrelated-histories switch during the pull, which allows me to add the commits of repoB, but they are all squashed in to one, and I want to preserve the history of these commits.

Answer (score -1):

To make it simple and *not* go back to having to do anything on svn, I would do this:

```
# create a new third repo
git init /home/myuser/blahblah
cd /home/myuser/blahblah
# add thr other two git repos as remotes
git remote add repo1 whatever-url-for-repo1
git remote add repo2 whatever-url-for-repo2
```

Now, each one of those two repos has a master, right? And repo2/master started from the third revision of repo1/master, right?

```
git checkout first-revision-of-repo2/master # checkout this revision by id
git reset --soft third-revision-of-repo1/master # this revision is also by its id
git commit -m "Same comment as repo2/4b"
```

At this point you have created 4b'. It's the same *content* of 4b *but* it has revision 3 as its parent

```
# now we roll all the other revisions from 4b to the tip of repo2/master
git cherry-pick revision-4b..repo2/master # original ID of revision 4b on repo2/master
```

At this point you now have the history of repo2/master on a new branch (still unnamed, you are working on detached HEAD) and it is related to repo1/master as it was supposed to exist originally. Have fun with it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try this, just want to clarify that it's repo2 in the checkout and reset commands and not repo1?

Comment: Reset uses a revision from repo1. Corrected the recipe